# Dynamically Generated Links in JSP not appearing

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying this code

```
for(Product product : catalog.getValues()){
String id = product.getId();
out.println("<a href=product.jsp?id=" + id + "/>");
```

}

And nothing is appearing when I run the jsp on server. The for loop is definitely being run - I think this may be a syntax issue.

What's wrong?

Comment: What is `out`? Is it HttpResponse.getOutputStream()`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure out doe snot need to be defined- it's a PrintWriter given to me by a JSP

Comment: Abu- no - but I didn't think I needed to

Comment: also try enclosing your url in href with `""` double quotes

Comment: actually, wait, no that won't work because product.jsp is an actual jsp

Comment: wait, can I do a get on a servlet through href? how do I specify which servlet?

Comment: yes just mention the product.jsp in the url mapping and whenever you click the link it will call the servlets doGet method.

Comment: ok, but the links are still not appearing - I tried taking out the + id part and still no dice, however, when I just put in id, it works

Comment: didnt you forget the anchor text `out.println("<a href=product.jsp?id=" + id + ">"+product.getName+"</a>");`

Comment: oh facepalm - I'm getting stupider with age - thanks for catching that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be with this, if there is no error on the server console:

```
out.println("<a href=product.jsp?id=" + id + "/>");
```

This should be:

```
out.println("<a href=product.jsp?id=" + id + ">My Links</a>");
```

The anchor tag `<a>` is not closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is said a lot but you should move away from using scriptlets in JSP files. you can achieve the same thing with JSTL

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${reuqestScope.catalog}" var="product">
    <a href=product.jsp id="${product.id}">Link</a>
</c:forEach>
```

and as stated in the comments you have forgotten to close the anchor text